# How to create an object from an interface that contains both data and delegate (TypeScript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I understood the following,

```
interface Teacher {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Func {
  (x: number, y: number): number;
}

const teacher: Teacher = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Aaron",
};
const add: Func = (x, y) => x + y;
```

but I have no idea how to create an object from the following interface?

```
interface TeacherFunc {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  (x: number, y: number): number;
}



// It is incomplete.
const tf: TeacherFunc = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Aaron",
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every function in JavaScript is an object, (specifically [a `Function` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)), but you cannot use [object literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to create a function object.  If you want to make a function object with additional properties on it, you will need to make a function and then add properties to it, either individually by setting them, or all at once by something like [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

First let's change `TeacherFunc`'s definition slightly:

```
interface TeacherFunc {
  id: number;
  teacherName: string;  // <-- changed name to teacherName
  (x: number, y: number): number;
}
```

I've decided to use the property named `teacherName` instead of `name`, for reasons I will explain later.

Anyway, you can make a `TeacherFunc` with `Object.assign()`, which copies properties to its first argument from its subsequent arguments:

```
const tf: TeacherFunc = Object.assign(
  (x: number, y: number) => x + y,
  {
    teacherName: "Aaron",
    id: 1,
  }
);
```

Or you can just make it a function first and add properties individually later, and the compiler will accept it due to support added in TypeScript 3.1 for [property declarations on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions):

```
const tf2: TeacherFunc = (x, y) => x + y;
tf2.teacherName = "Aaron";
tf2.id = 1;
```

So that's how you'd do it if you had `teacherName` instead of `name`.

---

But you had this:

```
interface TeacherFunc {
  id: number;
  name: string; // <-- back to name
  (x: number, y: number): number;
}
```

The version with `name` is tricky and weird, because [all functions have a read-only `name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).  So you'll get a `name` property for free just by making it a function, but you won't be able to change it by assignment.  If you want that name to be `"Aaron"`, you could try making the function itself named `Aaron`, which will work that way at least without minifiers or other JS transformation.  Or you could use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to set it.

So it could look like this:

```
const tf: TeacherFunc = Object.assign(
  function Aaron(x: number, y: number) { return x + y },
  {
    id: 1,
  }
);
console.log(tf.name); // "Aaron" hopefully
```

or this:

```
const Aaron: TeacherFunc = (x, y) => x + y;
Aaron.id = 1;
const tf2 = Aaron;
console.log(tf2.name); // "Aaron" hopefully
```

or this:

```
const tf3: TeacherFunc = (x, y) => x + y;
tf3.id = 1;
Object.defineProperty(tf3, "name", { value: "Aaron" });
console.log(tf3.name); // "Aaron" hopefully
```

But really, I'd stay away from any interface that was both callable and had a non-`readonly` `name` property, because it will let you do things that actual JavaScript functions will reject:

```
tf3.name = "oops" // no compiler error, but
//  ERROR at runtime: "name" is read-only
```

So I'd stick with `teacherName` or something.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkqJLAsgPIDWIAnnoccQJbAAuEATgGYVIAVCAgAW3AGIBXYPEbNmLACYAuEpLAAjbgG4i8pJ1HcAcuAiqo7LmwDmu-UgAUAD1XB1WrgBokdNx+4ASn9NHT1iAF8mZngAe2BLAx5VISMuKRkkAF4kSg0AKwh4dgA6ECgoFhtgR3DmFxDPHz81UK5A7IA+JGckAGpfLzriAgdiQ3gxLlNIVQAiAEEQLni5obGkJVUARnX9KPlA3Tq4hPYkgCYU4UmJaVkcl2aOrO7egbp7ZnYeC5KJqYzZA5RbLVZfca-EpKbJIbbHSLRUjQOCIJAAVRsIjkCg43D4aNSt3S9xx8i2rU8EOYyIsVls1OIDUp3GajSC7K41KiJ3iiR+1zSGQeuQKRVK5Uq1VqDh493YLHiSCWKxqrhZ3l8nI6uCQXAg7EkXGAPX6viQET28lGYwpu2GFrqR15CViGAgJQwsRsjh+JWRRyQAHog0hQaq5kgRLEYBA5RgMHRosRTokVfFBcThbCnr4Xm8zZ86ungNDFLD4S7+b9YSXqam3R6vT6fn8A9pg6Hw6sozG45IE0nk0hU+cfgBmTNTbOPZzPLqmj7UidlivUvKFYolRRxtgQAAKK1jXHYdF9PHHPjmyLWeCQADdMJJzGGS5GIs75A33Z7vefx-6ZiBiGr5gsAkbRrG8aJsOK7IrCcyxDGUCRiBwCxCOsRgDALDulwSDcCsmoaJI7B1CBgC8G4ApTtIAAogASvRlD0UgIDnFw0gKrMYY3psUB6sIigALTxDBehRBEQA)

Comment: Not easily, no.  Generally speaking class instances will not be callable.  You could do [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/mLR0kw) which (ab)uses the fact that you can make a class constructor return something other than `this`, and that works, sort of, but it's considered bad practice and has weird effects.  Is there some reason why you need a callable class instance?  Anyway, since this wasn't part of your original question, you should probably post a new question about it if you want a more detailed answer.